# Laravel 5.4 - Cannot update mysql table column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

So I'm using this DB facade and eloquent in updating table column

```
$affectedRows = DB::table('Users')
            ->where('Phone',$phonenumber)
            ->update(['IsActivated' => 'Y']);
```

or this one:

```
$affectedRows = Users::where('Phone','=',$phonenumber)
->update(['IsActivated' => 'Y']);
```

but I encountered this error when I access the url

```
 <span class="exception_message">SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (`0` = Phone and `1` = = and `2` = 0000000000) limit 1)</span>
```

Comment: What is the value of $phonenumber when you print it out? Maybe it is an array and not a number?

Comment: @Jack the phonenumber  value is 0000000000 it's a varchar.
ps. I change the phonenumber to 0000000000 since it's my personal number :)

Comment: Can you give the table definition?

Comment: Also check that the casing is correct on your column names. Generally it is not a good idea to use casing for column or tables names since mysql on windows is case insensitive for cols but a mac and linux respect casing so it's better to just stick with snake case. e.g. is_activated. This is the convention laravel uses anyway.

Comment: @imaji Looks like the value is not the issue then. What does running Users::where('Phone','=','0000000000')
->update(['IsActivated' => 'Y']); in artisan tinker give you?

Comment: @NigelRen I have the following:
UserId int(11) | 
Phone varchar(100) | 
IsActivated char(1)

Comment: @Jack I don't have any experience on how to use tinker ;) but tried it in my cmd : but below is the result

>php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.3 (PHP 5.6.29 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Users::where('Phone','=','0000000000') ->update(['IsActivated' => 'Y'])
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'users' not found in eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: In using tinker - try using \App\Users to specify how it should access the class.

Comment: @NigelRen I have 1 as the result:
>php artisan tinker
Psy\App\Users::where('Phone','=','000000000')->update(['IsActivated'=>'Y'])
=> 1
>>>

Comment: @Jack
below is the result 
 >php artisan tinker
Psy\App\Users::where('Phone','=','000000000')->update(['IsActivated'=>'Y'])
=> 1

Comment: @iamj Interesting. Do you run any other queries before the running the one you posted?

Comment: @Jack I didn't run any queries before this one :) 
I'm just using Postman to check the result

Comment: @iamji Can you try replacing $phonenumber with '000000' ?

Comment: @Jack tried replacing $phonenumber with '00000' and the update is successful. Anyways restarted mysql service today and tried accessing the /url , guess what it 's already fixed.

Comment: @iamj Glad you got it working, hard to say if it was a problem with the var or your env config.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help ;)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using

```
$affectedRows = Users::where('Phone',$phonenumber)->update(['IsActivated' => 'Y']);
```

Comment: Yes this one :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (`0` = Phone and `1` = = and `2` = 0000000000) limit 1)

Comment: Can you check the line number of the error.  Make sure there are no other attempts to fetch the user in the same page as well

Comment: It's in Connection.php line 647, There's no other fetching attempts since I'm using postman in accessing the URL

Answer (score 1):

Try these in this exact order and tell us at what commands give an error. Mind I use users and phone, not Users and Phone. It **won't** affect the query. First add these helper lines in your Users model, right above `class Users extends Model`

```
/**
 * App\User
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $phone
 * @property-read \App\User $user
 * @method static wherePhone($value)
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 */

$results = DB::table('users')->where('id', '1')->first();
dd($results);
$results = DB::table('users')->where('id', '1')->get();
dd($results);
$results = DB::table('users')->where(['phone' => '000000000000'])->get();
dd($results);
$results = DB::table('users')->where('phone', '000000000000')->get();
dd($results);
$results = DB::table('users')->where('phone', $phonenumber)->get();
dd($results);
$results = DB::table('users')->wherePhone($phonenumber)->get();
dd($results);
```

If none of these work, then there is a problem with your model. As no results can be found, an update is impossible. You can inter-exchange `DB::table('users')->where(...)` with `Users::where(...)`

Did you by any change called your User model `Users.php` instead of `User.php`? I had your problem a while ago but can't really remember what the cause was. It had to do with the User model settings.

Comment: Let me try that and btw I'm using User.php.

Comment: Hi Dimitri tried the above code and it was all successful.
Thank you for your response and I'm sorry for the late response. Tried to restart mysql today and now I was able to update the column

Comment: Pleasure bro, happy you found a way out. It was a strange error you were encountering.